# CUT OUT HEXAGONS

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Write a full program or a function taking an unsigned integer number N and doing this cut out work:

- Cut out a hollow hexagon 'donut' shape with side B-C equal to 2N times '/'
- Translate the piece above by 3 lines.
- Repeat the job N times (from the piece obtained) decrementing by 2 '/' side B-C , until smallest hexagon (2 times '/').

This is the smallest hexagon which will be cut out last:

```
    side B-C     C____D                      
    is 2'/' ->   /    \ 
               B/      \   
 side  C-D      \      /  
is 4'_'          \____/   
                A
```

Test cases:

N = 0 may output a blank sheet (nothing), but you don't heave to handle it.

N = 1:

```
  ____  
 /    \
/      \
\      / 
 \____/   
/      \   
\      /   
 \____/
```

N = 3:

```
          ____
        _/    \_
      _//      \\_
     // \      / \\
    //   \____/   \\   
   //   /______\   \\
  / \   \      /   / \
 /   \   \____/   /   \
/   / \          / \   \ 
\   \  \________/  /   / 
 \   \            /   / 
/ \   \          /   / \
\  \   \________/   /  / 
 \  \              /  / 
  \  \____________/  / 
   \                / 
    \              / 
     \____________/
```

N = 8:

```
                              ____                              
                            _/    \_                            
                          _//      \\_                          
                        _// \      / \\_                        
                      _///   \____/   \\\_                      
                    _////   /______\   \\\\_                    
                  _//// \   \______/   / \\\\_                  
                _/////   \   \____/   /   \\\\\_                
               //////   /_\          /_\   \\\\\\               
              ///// \   \__\________/__/   / \\\\\              
             /////   \   \____________/   /   \\\\\             
            /////   / \   \          /   / \   \\\\\            
           //// \   \  \   \________/   /  /   / \\\\           
          ////   \   \  \              /  /   /   \\\\          
         ////   / \   \  \____________/  /   / \   \\\\         
        /// \   \  \   \                /   /  /   / \\\        
       ///   \   \  \   \              /   /  /   /   \\\       
      ///   / \   \  \   \____________/   /  /   / \   \\\      
     // \   \  \   \  \                  /  /   /  /   / \\     
    //   \   \  \   \  \________________/  /   /  /   /   \\    
   //   / \   \  \   \                    /   /  /   / \   \\   
  / \   \  \   \  \   \                  /   /  /   /  /   / \  
 /   \   \  \   \  \   \________________/   /  /   /  /   /   \ 
/   / \   \  \   \  \                      /  /   /  /   / \   \
\   \  \   \  \   \  \____________________/  /   /  /   /  /   /
 \   \  \   \  \   \                        /   /  /   /  /   / 
/ \   \  \   \  \   \                      /   /  /   /  /   / \
\  \   \  \   \  \   \____________________/   /  /   /  /   /  /
 \  \   \  \   \  \                          /  /   /  /   /  / 
  \  \   \  \   \  \________________________/  /   /  /   /  /  
   \  \   \  \   \                            /   /  /   /  /   
    \  \   \  \   \                          /   /  /   /  /    
     \  \   \  \   \________________________/   /  /   /  /     
      \  \   \  \                              /  /   /  /      
       \  \   \  \____________________________/  /   /  /       
        \  \   \                                /   /  /        
         \  \   \                              /   /  /         
          \  \   \____________________________/   /  /          
           \  \                                  /  /           
            \  \________________________________/  /            
             \                                    /             
              \                                  /              
               \________________________________/
```

Rules:
 - Margins are not specified.
 - Standard loopholes are forbidden.
 - Standard input/output methods.
 - Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Sandbox : https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18143/84844

Comment: For n=3, it looks like you decrement it and then raise it one line, but I don't see that specified in the directions...Also where is the strip across the center coming from in the bottom twin of the smallest two?

Comment: @Jonah they are raised by 3 lines, I think you refer to the line you see just below the smallest one, if so it is a line of the biggest piece in background. I removed the diagonal strip because it was misleading.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDbDcMgDPz3FJ7AXsgSivrfn0odIf/tiFmE@EFsSE6AzJ19nHht7@/26R0nNAVMV7ZTimrMUUiRSsmolIYkbVDhhTUAHvtfl4tE3BxCZFPH/gsDwnJDUiIku8hsydbo2uir1JeLq4JkmrQBNp10hy8hzqP@kJLDWFaVwxyczDSZyBZgiqtpSEuUjBN/dpsp4el2ff3d6oneTw "Canvas – Try It Online")  maybe I am wrong but it looks like this to me..

Comment: [Close, yet so far away.. Let's just say I'm using translucent paper.. xD](https://tio.run/##ZZBRCsMwDEP/fQrfQBcyhNKffQwGuz9kstW6bSYIJFL8RLK/tu/@2d5zemtQ18naRgYxlmCgfCZnpADwEIqbuAL6TgoF3ldi8h@oShhwulCC0q6DcetIVyjXKdxwVLdUHxZedoxDqMhhdfk2kH4uw5rIT5R3ddf7gXqQ5Oc77tVdXy9fBlRTf/WPOn93RVFz/gA) Will continue when I have some more time, after I've figured out a rule to determine which parts are/aren't displayed in the final result to overwrite them with spaces.

Comment: @Arnauld the shapes are stacked "donut"-ish hexagons, so the outer part is opaque and inner - transparent (with the exception of the bottom one)

Comment: Suggested test case: [n=8](https://tinyurl.com/y4r34n7y). Contains multiple lines both inside and below the top 'donut'. [Here the output of my WIP attempt again to see the lines when everything is translucent.](https://tinyurl.com/y652w8mq)

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen can you add this n=8 test case please?

Comment: @AZTECCO Done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 80 bytes

```
Ｆ⮌…·¹Ｎ«→↘Ｆ²«Ｍ⁺³×⁴ι↑Ｐ×_⊗ι↙Ｆ⊗ι«ＦκＰ× ⁴↙¹»→Ｆι«ＦκＰ× ⁴↘¹»Ｆ⊖ι«ＦκＰ× ⁻×³ιλ↘¹»\Ｐ×_⊗ι»»‖ＢＯ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZIxa8MwEIVn@1ccniRQhzQZSrKVLIG6DabdAsVRzomoLBlZcinFv11VJGoCXUxHvXt87/QkfqkN17X0vtEGSIUDmh7JTnHpejFgVaszkgWDneqcfXbtEQ2hlMJ3npV6QLKuxPli6eb3uNWfapIi8z6a03gfqGTJ4FW02JMVA0Epg/Vbd3VnpZNWdEYoS5KheC8YbLU7SjyRYE2uKecJmxiTcm58MTCpHxT@YiFgV4mW7eNg4jFYRH2ckqbbJKD4Lz1ybvFpa@QGW1R2/ualUKHFJCyvFTKQdEZemhWHQzG/7TEf8wobidw@OmvRNPLrJfwRWXfhYTfeP/i7Qf4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⮌…·¹Ｎ«
```

Loop from the largest to the smallest hexagon.

```
→↘Ｆ²«Ｍ⁺³×⁴ι↑
```

Draw each hexagon twice in the desired location.

```
Ｐ×_⊗ι
```

Draw half of the top line of the hexagon.

```
↙Ｆ⊗ι«ＦκＰ× ⁴↙¹»
```

Draw the top left diagonal, but for each row erase 4 spaces first if this is the second hexagon.

```
→Ｆι«ＦκＰ× ⁴↘¹»
```

Draw half of the bottom left diagonal, still erasing 4 spaces first if this is the second hexagon.

```
Ｆ⊖ι«ＦκＰ× ⁻×³ιλ↘¹»
```

Draw almost all of the rest of the bottom left diagonal, erasing until the middle of the hexagon if this is the second hexagon.

```
\Ｐ×_⊗ι
```

Finish the bottom left diagonal and draw half of the bottom line of the hexagon.

```
»»‖ＢＯ²
```

Mirror everything at the end.

Alternative approach, also 80 bytes:

```
Ｆ⮌…·¹Ｎ«→↘Ｆ²«Ｍ⁺³×⁴ι↑ＦκＧ→⊗ι↓³←⊖⊗ι↙⊖⊗ι↘⊖⊗ι→⊖⊗ι↓³←⊗ι↖⊕⊗ι↗⊕⊗ι Ｐ×_⊗ι↙↙⊗ι→↘⊗ι↑Ｐ×_⊗ι»»‖Ｍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZI/a8MwEMXn@lMITxKoQ9oOxVmzBOJiTD0XRz07orIkZNmllHx2V/J/CKYZdfd79453YpfcMJWLriuUQTiFFkwN@CiZaGreQprLEvCOoqPUjX1rqjMYTAhBv8FDrFrAUcrLiyX76XlQ33Iu9TOfenhoJ24qfqbonVdQ4xeKOCEURZn29IB/EZQo8VMqOc6m6KCas4BPzD3rDShyM6ITFL4JzEAF0jpgASfyHmZy2YT@BW52Wi@c6aHoMt2QZ3p02ERCFPYJxY2wXBsuLR4iDD/CtR0ZqPkS3rkvJb1mHcmiWSTz4db8zRFWgvFwd611Da5BCoUAZmNujHL/aN91r91jK/4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⮌…·¹Ｎ«
```

Loop from the largest to the smallest hexagon.

```
→↘Ｆ²«Ｍ⁺³×⁴ι↑
```

Draw each hexagon twice in the desired location.

```
ＦκＧ→⊗ι↓³←⊖⊗ι↙⊖⊗ι↘⊖⊗ι→⊖⊗ι↓³←⊗ι↖⊕⊗ι↗⊕⊗ι
```

Before drawing the second hexagon, erase the area between it and the next smaller hexagon.

```
Ｐ×_⊗ι↙↙⊗ι→↘⊗ι↑Ｐ×_⊗ι»»‖Ｍ
```

Draw the left half of each hexagon, and then mirror everything at the end.

Answer (score 4):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>113</s> 112 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
«/＊α_×－／═↔⁸３＋ ＊－╶Ｒ⇵｛；Ｘ：«ｗ╷/###/＊Ｋｋｙ┤_×＋－ｙ#×/×－ｙ_×－／═ŗ∙ #⟳#¶#╋# ⟳_╋↔ｘ“kｙv╴e┌/ｉ┴⁰U＜ａlisｓfr↖；,ｉmＦE！↷qB╪²－‟＃ŗ｝#∙ ╋↔║
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=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__,i=NQ__,v=8)

A part of the answer is literally evaluating the JavaScript `p.p.overlap(p.p,0,p.p,(a,b)=>b==0?a:b)`..

Comment: I was wondering where the evaluation would be useful. Pretty cool!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 374 bytes

```c
#define F(X,R)*d=*(d=o+x*(l*3+35-g)+x/2+X+R)-32?*d:R?
i,z,x,l,w,r,g,m;f(n){int*d,o[i=z=(x=n*8+1)*(n*5+4)],*c=o;for(;l=i--;)*c++=i%x?32:10;for(;l++<n;)for(g=35;i=g-29;g-=3){for(r=m+=m=w=l*2;r--;F(~-w*x-w,r)g:g)F(w*~x,r)95:95,F(w*x-w,r)95:95;for(;w--;)for(r=4;r--;F(m-~w*~-x,-r)g:47)F(w-m-w*x,r)g:47,F(w-m-~w*x,r)g:92,F(m+~w-w*x,-r)g:92;}for(;i<z;++i)printf(o[i]-35?o+i:" ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDBisIwEIbv@xTispBkMuzaWLSNQ28@gCdh8SCtDYEmXcpCg2Jf3U2se8v/TfLNZGqsu7M3j8d7c2mtvyz27CgPXDQkWEM9BME6oUDlaDiEzwyOcOCosko05aF6s/Iqg@zkKAdppNMt8/xm/a9oZP9t6UoskBdbWHHBvMhhzU9S1NTrth@Y7sgiai5qALIfoVJZufp6lQB2XvN0NqRybclgVmiDpPgt0YEckKOROpHpIWr2bMJRBIyjcFMavmejmEIMRV4WuUxxLj7z3GVM7Wfb@iVxOMV3GCQmzXqTPOiSWc5AzmD6J0UWiYNpfN7BGen70293Vw1g@c8Qd9KyuJITqrzqwZbLxZLr@8OdrWfxR2yb0h8)

-33 more saved by @ceilingcat improvement

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/),   [<s>433</s>](https://tio.run/##fZBPb6MwEMXv/hSWUBX/GS8pIeoGx8st3HNpq01VRRBSS0BWJBE0afLVs7ZBtJVWC4d5fh5@b5hUpMW62t5uXrbJdbXBC/IMT/AIS8oyxUimUvHMn/gjX1IxCWKWRcsYaThBC@9QQAM1ZJDAFkqZk4qe07d1zVJgGex@a3VSpFUV@8nvKSPvRk15SF9kvqtJqnZSCyEpSzlX@q6NR3gU3Y/dZaHGsuB8Xklqj4k5JvNQJlxN6HmrRt5IJNIQeMsKFvCEtbz1A16wVjbKOLJUISscqlYBa2Rtk84L0rAWRANjqOlsGs2mckHEvzzSCDPy4G@jrbxYmmwsqOOGHbWHlnYXpjF8gAW5frNmAXRNJVwbEIN1/e6FD12GNn@r5yfJuaZ/jge7UWKW@SIm09jWaBJQebn5DGGMPc9b2erEhxVzhbN63WCdY7NRtDIX1v5AuJeuC@e63h@w2SRC2PccxhUrVp3wu09sNRGv5vlvq23wHRvvN@muylx@76wwWnVqaHVU1Jkd3Io@wDYOIUZ7n0HW/hrmhvkSY68/o4ZmQ3GMOO45uJtjmKV/mY88XaXFMdvg@f6Q6d2Pt18I6eqAy7WuCMVnhHIyodINXG8Ox7rCY4kuCN3@Ag)  [<s>412</s>](https://tio.run/##XZBBb4JAEIXv/RXGpsnuzmyqLKSFdcIN7l7UNB4MCNlkgYY0YdXoX7eAtja9zbx5883kZTKzu7q8Xp/zfWHq/SRhG1zjCpdc5CRYTpncwBpWsORSebHIo2X8ZPCIDg9oscMWc0yxxEoXrOYnU3@JDEWOzYehIzFHtXiHORfs0FcB@Hyri6ZlGTXakpFSc5EBkHlxsfKi@WycaguwqDUf6pRm2lC68HUKpPipJBXIVPcAcMIKBalw4F493ZEV3rjeUkW@sLrt8QlzshMOZYczbHkZlTxhf4QwiMIAEyb/a7dHuuHDG9O/8y6Ds8JLh3Lg@W8/wGqIY1Tw7vqVQg9vpsde6OnzeMIsjpoboM@2D69gfXBbqYK4ARNNJ1Ouz9dqZ2rGTwVTQ/cN)   407 bytes

```c
#define F(Y,X,W,R)*d=*(d=c-Y+X+W+R)-32?*d:R?
i,z,x,l,w,r,d,G,g,m;f(n){int*c,*d,o[i=z=(x=n*8+1)*(n*5+4)];for(c=o;l=i--;)*c++=i%x?32:10;for(;l++<n;)for(G=0;i=G<4;G+=3){g=35-G;c=o+x*l*3+G*x+x/2;for(r=m+=m=w=l*2;r--;F(x-w*x,-w,0,r)g:g)F(w*x,-w,0,r)95:95,F(-w*x,-w,0,r)95:95;for(;w--;)for(r=4;r--;F(~w*x,m,~w,-r)g:47)F(w*x,-m,w,r)g:47,F(~w*x,-m,w,r)g:92,F(w*x,m,~w,-r)g:92;}for(;i<z;)i+=printf(o[i]-35?o+i:" ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDLasNADEX3/YrQUpiRNDTxg9aeCO/sfTZJKFkEOzYD9riYgoeE5NdT20kfdCddXR2Jm6u83tvqen0qDqWxh1kqtrShNa0kFAyi4FxtcYNrXEnlewkU8Sp5MHQkRzX11FFBGVXU6FJYeTL2E3KCgtp3w0cWji284UKCsBBiIHe6bDuRc6trNkppCTkim2eX@F68mE9TXSMurZZjnfFcG86Wgc6QfXmq2A9VpgcAOqjBxwwcuhdvWuy4QW645xo83Q30VDjVgyPV05w6WcWVTMUfIQrjKKRUqP/a7Y9@fPAGDu68y@hs6NKTGnnB6zewGbOYFLq7fqTIo5vpdy/y9Hk6YZZHLQ3yRzckV4ohtZ3yw6RFEz/OHqU@X5u9sUKeSuGP3Rc)

-21 thanks to @ceilingcat
-5 @ceilingcat + y removed

```c
   ###\  
    ###\   <= we  draw only on spaces ' '  
\###     
 \###        first time we draw '#' for collisions

 /####\  
/######\ 
\######/  
 \####/ 

  ____
 /####\        then we move our drawing pointer
/######\     3 lines below
\######/
 \____/         and we draw spaces 
/      \       instead of # 
\      /
 \____/


      ____
    _/####\
   //######\     and we repeat for bigger donuts
  /#\######/   moving our drawing pointer 
 /###\____/      
/###/      \ 
\###\      /
 \###\____/
  \####??####/
   \________/
```